# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.link (http://127.0.0.1:8080/application/app.js:23:25)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:16:71
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:83:480
    at ta (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:84:35)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:69:226)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:79:323
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:134:167
    at m.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:148:47)
    at m.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:145:92) <table-list list="{{searchList}}" class="ng-isolate-scope">

 // app.js
var app = angular.module('myglamm', []);

//controller
app.controller('datalist', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


  $http.get('json/data.json')
    .then(function(response) {

      $scope.searchList = response.data.appointments;
      console.log($scope.searchList);
    });
}]);

app.directive('tableList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      list: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'myTable.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.data = JSON.parse(scope.list);
      console.log(scope.data);
    }
  };
});
```

I'm trying to display data in table with directive isolate scope.

Comment: Code looks good, create plunker.

Comment: The $http service automatically parses the response data from the server. There is no need to do it in a directive.

Comment: Also use one-way `<` binding instead of attribute `@` binding.